# Сортировка пузырьком с удалением дубликатов. Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range. Хоть по идее все правильно

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Надо отсортировать список и удалить дубликаты.

```
lst1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 10, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 98, 67]


def bubble_sort_no_double(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] == arr[j + 1]:
                del arr[j]
                n -= 1
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]


bubble_sort_no_double(lst1)
print(lst1)
```

При первой итерации n = 13, а j принимало бы значения от 0 до 11. Как только j = j+1, то j удаляется, а значение n уменьшается на 1. Тем самым при первом проходе j (когда i = 0) после удаления дубликатов n = 11.Из range(0, n - i - 1) следует, что последнее значение которое дольно принять j это 9, после чего цикл завершится (i станет равно 1 и т.д.). Но этого не происходит. Почему-то j становится 10, после чего при попытке сравнить arr[j] == arr[j + 1] возникает ошибка ибо в списке нет элемента с индексом 11.
Вопрос где я не прав (почему код не работает). Если не сложно подскажите как правильно.

Comment: Нельзя удалять элементы из списка, под которому идёт  итерация.

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаете в range() число, почему вдруг вы решили, что при сокращении списка это как-то отразится на границах цикла? Как было `range (12)`, так и осталось.

И даже если бы было `range(len(arr))` , то проблема бы осталась - инициализация цикла происходит один раз и дальнейшие манипуляции со списком на цикле не отражаются.

Вместо удаления ненужных элементов из исходного списка нужно добавлять нужные в новый.

Comment: О это я  хотел услышать. Понял. Спасибо большое

Comment: Пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то разумно сначала удалить дубликаты, а потом то что осталось - отсортировать.
Удалить дубликаты можно вот так:

```
lst1=list(set(lst1))
```

Ну а далее - сортируйте, хоть пузырьком, хоть чем пожелаете. Ну, например, пузырьком

```
def bubble_sort(lst):
    n = 1 
    while n < len(lst):
         for i in range(len(lst)-n):
              if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
                   lst[i],lst[i+1] = lst[i+1],lst[i]
         n += 1
    return (lst)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я знаю что так можно. Просто препод сказал не использовать set. А  когда я сделал через цикл. Он спросил можно ли ускорить работу кода, ну я подумал и сказал, что можно(подумал что если убирать во время сортировки, то будет быстрее). Сейчас я понимаю, что похоже нет, нельзя. Даже так, хотелось бы понять почему у меня код не работает

Comment: @Vladimir " Я знаю что так можно. Просто препод сказал не использовать set." -  очень мило.  А написать про это в условиях вопроса -  не? Пусть люди помучаются, подумают, попытаются мне помочь, а я уж там потом посмотрю, что у них получилось.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае лучше сделать так:

```
def bubble_sort_no_double(arr):
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr)-1:
        j = 0
        while j < len(arr) - i - 1:
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            elif arr[j] == arr[j + 1]:
                del arr[j]
            j += 1
        i += 1
```

Ну или так:

```
def bubble_sort_no_double(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    i = 0
    while i < n-1:
        j = 0
        while j < n - i - 1:
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            elif arr[j] == arr[j + 1]:
                del arr[j]
                n -= 1
            j += 1
        i += 1
```

---

Для `Python-3.9` и выше:

```
def bubble_sort_no_double(arr):
    i = -1
    while (i:=i+1) < len(arr)-1:
        j = -1
        while (j:=j+1) < len(arr) - i - 1:
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            elif arr[j] == arr[j + 1]:
                del arr[j]
```

И, соответственно, так:

```
def bubble_sort_no_double(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    i = -1
    while (i:=i+1) < n-1:
        j = -1
        while (j:=j+1) < n - i - 1:
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            elif arr[j] == arr[j + 1]:
                del arr[j]
                n -= 1
```